# How to properly iterate through directory names with os.stat?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pull a list of top level directories under C:/Folder.
I want to then check the modified date for each directory.  I can use

```
next(os.walk(source_dir))[1]
```

to get a list of directories.

But when I try and use

```
os.stat(str(dir_list))[stat.ST_MTIME]
```

to get the modified date for each directory, it seems to be searching for all directory names as one large name.
This gives me a File Not Found error.
How can I get the modified date for each subdirectory without getting a File Not Found error?

```
import os.path
import time, stat

# Source directory
source_dir  = r'C:/Folder'

def check_dir():

    if not os.path.isdir(source_dir):
        # Needed to detect top level files
        print("Nothing in top folder.")
    else:
        dir_list = next(os.walk(source_dir))[1]
        print(dir_list)
        # get modified time for directories
        dtime = os.stat(str(dir_list))[stat.ST_MTIME]
        if time.time() - dtime <= 7776000:
            print("Found modification in last 90 days for folder =>", dir_list, time.ctime(dtime))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_dir()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't use `os.stat` for a list you have to iterate over the list:

```
def check_dir():
    if not os.path.isdir(source_dir):
        # Needed to detect top level files
        print("Nothing in top folder.")
    else:
        root, dir_list, _ = next(os.walk(source_dir))
        print(dir_list)
        # get modified time for directories
        for dir in dir_list:
            dtime = os.stat(str(root + os.path.sep + dir))[stat.ST_MTIME]
            if time.time() - dtime <= 7776000:
                print("Found modification in last 90 days for folder =>", dir, time.ctime(dtime))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_dir()
```

Comment: This give me a weird output.  It lists all the directory names multiple times.

Comment: In the ```print()``` command you have to change ```dir_list``` to ```dir``` then you get the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `os.walk` gives you a relative path to the `source_dir` for example:

```py
import os

source_dir = '/tmp/'
relative_paths = [relative_path for relative_path in next(os.walk(source_dir))[1]]
print(relative_paths)

>>> ['com.google.Keystone', 'com.apple.launchd.liNmfkel1M', 'powerlog']
```

In order to get the stats you need to use the full path of each folder, for example:

```py
import os
import stat

source_dir = '/tmp/'
full_paths = [os.path.join(source_dir, relative_path) for relative_path in next(os.walk(source_dir))[1]]
print(full_paths)

>>> ['/tmp/com.google.Keystone', '/tmp/com.apple.launchd.liNmfkel1M', '/tmp/powerlog']
```

And then you can use them:

```py
import os
import stat

source_dir = '/tmp/'
full_paths = [os.path.join(source_dir, relative_path) for relative_path in next(os.walk(source_dir))[1]]
stats = [os.stat(path)[stat.ST_MTIME] for path in full_paths]
print(stats)

>>> [1581523169, 1581523164, 1581523141]
```